# Why images not display in when i run Expo react native standalone apk in my device?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have created a react native app project in expo but when i run in emulator all images are displayed but when i run after build apk all images are dissapeares amd not loading.

Please any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run expo publish before making the build.
Run:
`expo publish`
and then use `eas build`.
Expo publish will publish all your assets, including your images, and they will display in your next build. After you add any photo, run `expo publish` and then create build for your app.